# Can't detect if field null in report writer using IIF and IsNull()

Tags: acumatica

I need to detect if an APTran has a related APAdjust row. In the report writer, I've used the following statements to test if APAdjust.AdjdRefNbr is null or not:

```
=IIF(IsNull( [APAdjust.AdjdRefNbr], 0) = 0, 0, [APTran.CuryExpenseAmt])

=IIF([APAdjust.AdjdRefNbr]=NULL, 0, [APTran.CuryExpenseAmt])

=IIF([APAdjust.AdjdRefNbr] IS NULL, 0, [APTran.CuryExpenseAmt])
```

All three above statements have not worked. Please tell me what I'm missing.

EDIT:

Realized I was using the wrong field. I meant to use APTran.CuryTransAmt. Solution provided by HB works as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is type coercion going on with the report designer. I had success treating null as empty string for null check:

```
=IIF(Trim([APAdjust.AdjdRefNbr]) <> '', [APTran.CuryExpenseAmt], 0)
```

Comment: I copied your code and pasted into the report and it is still returning 0 instead of the extended value. Looking at what the report generated query returns, there should be one line showing the expense amount.

Comment: What does the report display for the value [APAdjust.AdjdRefNbr] when it's value is null? Also what is the value of [APTran.CuryExpenseAmt] at that moment?

Comment: HBAcumatica, I have an update. I am going to add it to my original question.

Comment: I just realized that I was looking at the wrong field... I was supposed to be using APTran.CuryTranAmt. Your solution works as well, thank you for your help!